# Is there a way to show real ads in open test

Tags: android, admob, opentest

I have an android app runnig as "Open Test" on google play. Banner and native test ads working fine, ad requests and impressions are displayed in admob but there appear no real ads on the devices even I install the app from google play. How to show real ads in Google Play Open Test?

Comment: Have you connect the app to AdMob? AdMob have reviewed the app?

Comment: Hello FreeLearning, thank you for your reply. Yes the app is connected to AdMob - App was reviewed by AdMob and Google Play. App-ID is set in Gradle file and Ad-Id's too.

Comment: So the app ID and ad unit ID are real (and not test) and the device you use isn't registered as a test device?
In all of this, test ads keep popping up?

Comment: Yes, real ID's and so on. Device is not registered as a test device. Tried on serveral devices

Comment: Then i believe that the issue going other my skills. I advice you to post the question also in this forum: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk. There Google employees will answer you to solve the issue (usually in less then a day), I think that that forum is the best place to get the answer and the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much FreeLearning. I will do that.